# What should the comment look like to be included as documentation for hubot?

Tags: hubot

As far as I've understood the `hubot help` command is supposed to list all commands based on the comment in the start of each script. For some reason it doesn't list the help for my file, can anyone spot the error?

```
# Description:
#   Hubot interface to octopus deploy
#
# Commands:
#   hubot octo promote <project> from <env1> to <env2> - Hubot deploys the latest release of <project> on <env1> to <env2>
#   hubot octo deploy <project> version <version> to <env> - Hubot deploys the specified version of <project> to <env>
#   hubot octo status - Hubot prints a dashboard of environments and currently deployed versions.
#
# Author:
#   kneumei


_ = require('underscore')._
q = require('q')
util = require('util')
....
```

The full script is here: https://github.com/mastoj/hubot-octopus/blob/master/src/octopus.coffee

Answer (score 0):

Did you ever get this to work? I'm struggling with the same problem. After pushing to heroku, it looks like the hubot-octopus module is built just fine, and I've included it in external-scripts.json along with the rest of the modules, but hubot does not list the octo commands in help and does not respond to octo commands.

```
remote: -----> Build succeeded!
remote:        ├── hubot@2.16.0
remote:        ├── hubot-diagnostics@0.0.1
remote:        ├── hubot-google-images@0.2.2
remote:        ├── hubot-google-translate@0.2.0
remote:        ├── hubot-help@0.1.2
remote:        ├── hubot-heroku-keepalive@1.0.0
remote:        ├── hubot-maps@0.0.2
remote:        ├── hubot-octopus@0.0.1              <----
remote:        ├── hubot-pugme@0.1.0
remote:        ├── hubot-redis-brain@0.0.3
remote:        ├── hubot-rules@0.1.1
remote:        ├── hubot-scripts@2.16.2
remote:        ├── hubot-shipit@0.2.0
remote:        └── hubot-slack@3.4.1
```

**UPDATE:** It turns out my problem was actually that the environment variable for the Octopus API Key was wrong. When this was not correctly set, it just silently failed.. I used OCTOPUS_API_KEY as stated in the documentation, but the actual implementation requires OCTOPUS_KEY. Added a pull request to hubot-octopus to fix the docs.